# Descent (Nerekhall expansion) bleeding mechanics

Tags: descent

The bleeding condition reads:

"(One action): Discard this card or token. For each other action you resolve while you have this card or token, suffer 1 (one fatigue)"

Should "each other action" be interpreted to mean that every 2 actions my hero takes, the effect of bleeding is applied? Or should "each other action" be interpreted to mean that the effect of bleeding should be applied once to every action that is not the above noted "discarding" action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of rephrasing may help clarify the intent of this condition:

> (One Action):  Discard this card or token.  For **any action, other than discarding this condition,** you resolve, suffer 1 fatigue.